# Paypal 10418 error

Tags: paypal

I am getting an error while doing express checkout for australian currency in PayPal. (The currencies of the shopping cart amounts must be the same) My code works fine with US dollars.

I set the currency code "AUD" correctly in both `setexpresscheckout` and `doexpresscheckout` process, but I am still getting an error.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to set the currency? This is outdated but possibly helpful: http://forums.asp.net/t/1246395.aspx/1

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously not sending the same currency in both SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.
USD is the 'main' currency. This means that if no currency is specified, it falls back on USD by default. Which is why if you don't specify anything, it works properly.

Review (or post) your code for both SetExpressCheckout and DoExpressCheckoutPayment, as I'm sure you're not properly specifying CURRENCYCODE for either of the API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I get same error code in soap message (`10418`) and get usefull description (`The currencies of the shopping cart amounts must be the same.`) in same soap message. I call `setExpressCheckout` with `EUR` currency, but I adjusted in my test account US country. My mistake occured this problem.

So it is always usefull check test/normal account adjustment!

Answer (score -1):

I had this error and it was because the `PaymentDetailType` was not completed correctly.
Make sure both `ItemTotal` and `OrderTotal` have a `BasicAmountType` entered.